# Firebase user is not able to login

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I am making an app for ios where I use firebase to authenticate users.

In the app I have App check so it used the apple certificates for the app to work without problems, but it took time to upload it to the apple store so my account has already expired and I no longer want to use the app check.

What happens to me is now every time I try to log in to the app, it returns the uid and the user, but it doesn't save it to the app, so I never stay logged in.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
      Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                log.error(error)
            }

                print(result?.user.uid)
    //Does print the uid correctly
            }
```

Here returns nill:

```
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ [weak self] auth, user in
            if((user) == nil){
                print("Not Logged in")
                return
            }
            
            print(user)
//Nill after succesfully logedin
            
            self?.observe(user: user)
            self?.userSession = user
        })
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "but it doesn't save it to the app". Please edit the question to explain what you're observing and how that isn't working the way you expect, along with all of the relevant code and your debugging detail on that code.

Comment: @DougStevenson the user dosnt keep signed in

Comment: How do you observe that?  We can't see what you're seeing, and we can't see the code you use to build your UI based on the state of the sign-in. All you are showing is code to sign in and code to respond to the sign-in state.  But we can't tell when you call those bits of code or how they interact with each other.